# How Does X build its modelist?

Tags: linux, xorg

I have an embedded board running Linux 3.0.35 and X.Org 1.14.4.  I'm modifying an existing framebuffer driver to support a new connector type. I'm reading the EDID, creating a new modelist using the fb_ functions, and can see the correct mode list in /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes.

However, the X server only seems to pick up these modes at start.  If I start X with a monitor connected, it will see the correct mode list and xrandr will allow me to switch modes.  However, if I start X without a monitor, after I connect it the framebuffer driver presents the correct modelist but not xrandr.  The latter only shows the default mode I set if no monitor is detected.

Given the version of kernel and X server I'm using, is there a standard way to notify the X server to reload its mode list?  Do most X drivers expect to read the EDID over i2c themselves and generate their own mode list?

Or do I need to do something with say a udev rule executed on monitor hotplug to run a script that uses xrandr to clear the mode list and add new ones based on the modes found in the framebuffer driver?

Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: maybe [`xdpyinfo`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xdpyinfo.1.html) could be of some use? and `xset` can enable/disable energy-star stuff, so possibly it could help - that may be a bit of a reach though...

Comment: So far it doesn't look like it.  I have been able to use cvt and xrandr to create the new modes I know are compatible with the monitor.  And also delete those modes when the monitor is unplugged.  However, it appears you can't use xrandr to delete those modes that were created when X was started.